# "Error in Success callbackId: FirebasePlugin223329663 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of null"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Am running in to this error where I can't navigate to the next using `navCtr` in ionic while using `cordova-plugin-firebase` link to the [repo](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase).

My `ts` file

```
    window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 60, function (credential) {
        console.log(credential);
        let verificationId = credential.verificationId;
        this.navCtrl.push(AuthDeviceVerifyPage, { verificationid: verificationId });
    }
```

The error am getting

```
        [INFO:CONSOLE(309)] "Error in Success callbackId: FirebasePlugin1582498724 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'goToVerify' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (309)
        [INFO:CONSOLE(311)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'goToVerify' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (311)
```

I/PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
                           getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

Comment: The error in the title is not the same as in your question. Could you clarify what's the actual error and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Also make sure you're careful with scoping: `this` might not be what you're expecting in the callback. In doubt debug or log what `this` actually is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by making an object and using the object as follows.

```
 // add a local variable to store navCtrl object
        let thatNavCtrl = this.navCtrl;
        window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 60, function (credential) {
            let verificationId = credential.verificationId;
            thatNavCtrl.push(AuthDeviceVerifyPage, { verificationid: verificationId });

        }, (error) => {
              console.error(error);
        });

    }
```